# Link Linux file path to a command

Tags: linux, opensuse, xampp

I would like to link the path to the file /opt/lampp/lampp to the word lampp in openSUSE. So I can simply type `lampp start` instead of `/opt/lampp/lampp start` Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three possibilities: either, make an alias:

```
alias lampp=/opt/lampp/lampp
```

or, add /opt/lampp to your PATH:

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp
```

or, make a link to your bin (and add this bin to your PATH):

```
ln -s /opt/lampp/lampp $HOME/bin/
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```